# How to customize stub request using Faraday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, faraday

I'm trying to customize stubs via Faraday and have a little problem with setting request_body and request_headers. All test works and are green, but I'm still getting message by Rubymine: „Found extra argument“ and that part of the code is underlined in red. I would like to get rid of it. Just how to customize body and headers in right way, please?

Actual problem

[image: 1]

I have tried to customize it like this:

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: "url") do |faraday|
        faraday.response :raise_error
      end

conn.get("url") do |req|
  req.body: {body: "body"}
  req.headers: {headers: "headers"}
end
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Not sure what ruby mine is trying to tell you because your code is correct, could just be an issue with method reflection as it is very hard for the IDE to determine how to reflect in an interpreted dynamic language like ruby. Also those methods are defined dynamically which might be causing issues. [Source](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/v2.7.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb#L197) That being said your "customization" looks wrong. I think it should be `req.body = "body"` and `req.headers = {your: "headers"}`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. :) But I'm still getting "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String" if I'm trying it the second way. The problem line is `conn.get("url") do |req|`.

Comment: If "body" is actually an `Array` you will need to call `to_json` e.g. `req.body = body.to_json`. There is nothing wrong with either way you are calling `conn.get`  [`Faraday::Connection#get`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Connection#get-class_method)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback.
This is a known problem, please follow the [RUBY-30140/False-positive-found-extra-argument-warning-with-Faraday.get](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-30140/False-positive-found-extra-argument-warning-with-Faraday.get)(see [help](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827497-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications%C2%A0) if you are not familiar with YouTrack).

I've requested this issue to include in one of our nearest maintenance sprint. Sorry for inconveniences:(

Best regards
Anna Kutarba.

JetBrains
https://jetbrains.com
The Drive to Develop